# Atribuir elemento a matriz apenas quando houver espaço?

Tags: c, matriz, random

Tenho alguns vetores que deve atribuir numa matriz 20x20, porem nenhum vetor pode sobrescrever o outro e nem ser imprimido em linhas diferentes, devem ser atribuídos em vertical ou horizontal.
Por exemplo, tenho os vetores :

```
int a[8] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

int b[7] ={7459015};

int c[6] ={5,4,3,7,9,1};
```

E uma matriz *20x20* quero inserir os vetores `a` e `b` em horizontal e o `c` na vertical, mas isso em uma ordem aleatória, sempre que rodar o programa ele vai atribuir a, b e c em lugares diferentes. Porém esses números não podem se sobrescrever, ou seja, todos devem estar na matriz por completo e além disso devem estar na vertical ou horizontal, sem mudar de coluna caso seja vertical, e sem mudar de linha caso seja horizontal.

Tentei gerar uma semente aleatória de linha e coluna para isso, e usei uma matriz definida com todos elementos valendo `-1`, até ai tudo bem, porém como verifico se o meu vetor cabe naquela posição gerada pelo `rand`? Isso sem sobrescrever outro numero que não seja -1 ?

Não vou postar o código porque é bem simples, apenas um `rand` para linha e coluna e ir atribuindo o vetor a matriz, não fiz nenhum tratamento para saber se há espaço para o vetor na matriz, por não saber mesmo.

Em resumo, é como gerar uma posição da matriz aleatória e ver se tem espaço na orientação (vertical ou horizontal) para receber meu vetor. Sem sobre escrever nenhum numero que não seja `-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de verificar se o espaço está disponível antes de escrever os valores. Também tens de verificar se a posição aleatória não sai do espaço existente.

Suponhamos que querias meter 5 valores horizontalmente a partir de (1, 1);

```
bool disponivel;
do {
    disponivel = true;
    startx = 1; // ou escolha aleatoria
    starty = 1; // ou escolha aleatoria
    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        if (a[starty][startx + k] != -1) { disponivel = false; break; )
    }
} while (!disponivel);
// aqui já podes atribuir valores no array
```